# I changed my admin model, now I cant submit the form (trying to connect username to article)

Tags: python, django

I was trying to connect the user to the article by making him the "author". It works now, kinda. I can submit through the admin interface and it recognizes my superuser as the author, but when I try and go through my forms like I did before the admin model, it just refreshes the page and doesn't submit.

`Models.py`:

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    body = models.TextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

`Views.py`:

```
# Create your views here.
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from articles_base.models import article
from forms import ArticleForm
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.context_processors import csrf

 
def articleReadView(request, id):
    article_ref = article.objects.get(id = id)
    args = {"article_title" : article_ref.title, "article_body" : article_ref.body, 'full_name' : request.user.username}
    return render_to_response('read_article.html', args)
                                                     
    
def articleSubmissionView(request):
    
    if request.POST:
            form = ArticleForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/article/1') #change this later to wherever we want to redirect them
    
    else:
        form = ArticleForm()
        
    args = {'full_name' : request.user.username}
    args.update(csrf(request)) 
    args['form'] = form
    return render_to_response('submit_article.html', args)
```

`Submission Template`:

```
<html>
    
   
    
    <head> 
    
        <title> Submit Article </title> 
        
        <style>
            
            textarea{
             
             resize : none;
                
            }
            
            #submitButton{
                
                position: fixed;
                top: 30em;
                left: .5em;
                
            }
            
        </style>
        
    </head>
    
    <body>
        
        <p> Logged in as {{full_name}} </p>
       <center>  <h1> Submit Article </h1> </center>
        
        <form action = "/article_submission/" method="post"> {% csrf_token %} <!-- side note.. had to look up how to comment in html, thats embarassing -->
            
            <h2> Title </h2>
            {{ form.title }}
           
            <h2> Body </h2>
            {{ form.body }} 
            
            
            <input type="submit" id = "submitButton">
        
        </form>
        
    </body>
    
</html>
```

`Admin.py`:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from articles_base.models import article
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'author')
    fieldsets = [
        (None, { 'fields': [('title','body')] } ),
    ]

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.author = request.user
        obj.save()

admin.site.register(article, ArticleAdmin)
```

Comment: Ok I've been messing with it and the problem it now submits, but throws a valueerror in the admin interface. The problem is in models.py, I changed it to ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True). I comment out null and blank, and the value error goes away, but the submit error comes back.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing your form is like,

```
class ArticleForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = article
        exclude = ('author',)
```

You just need to exclude it from the form, then set it in the view.

You need to assign the user instance to author, Because author is related to user.

```
if request.POST:
    form = ArticleForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
       form.save(commit=False)
       form.author = request.user
       form.save()
       return HttpResponseRedirect('/article/1')
```

Comment: I'm assuming you mean without the extra stuff in the view and the admin model? If so, I tried that (and just tried it again) and it doesn't work. It doesn't assign any specific user as the author for some reason. It recognizes that it should be a user, and allows me to choose from users in the admin interface, but it doesn't automatically assign the current user as the author. Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: Do you want to add the author in admin or in your views(own templates) ?